# How I can run task once?

Tags: deployment, newrelic, ansible

There is playbook for deploying many hosts.

I need to send the meaning of a variable ОNCE (run local_action once?!) to REST service after deploy.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

As the playbook are ment to be idempotent, I would say that the easiest way to do this would be to run a bash script that:

- Check if a file, let's say /var/lock/foobar, exists
- Execute the call on your WebService IF the file does not exists
- Write /var/lock/foobar

So you script is idempotent and can be called numerous time but making the call only once.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a task to the end of the deploy playbook?

```
-  hosts: rest_service_target
   tasks: 
     - name: Post to REST 
       local_action: command curl {{ url_of_rest_service_target }} {{ curl_arguments }}
```

Could add some error handling so this is done only when deploy is successful, send an email when deploy fails, etc. http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_error_handling.html